# Import several csv files as seperate variables using def function

Tags: pandas, csv, import, merge, filepath

I am trying to import several csv files that are all in the same folder and store them as seperate variables based on how i call the def function. in this case ticker.

Previously I had this:

```
#MSCI World
urth = pd.read_csv (r'.\CSV Files\urth.csv') 
urth.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

#MSCI Emerging Markets
eem = pd.read_csv (r'.\CSV Files\eem.csv')
eem.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

#International Corporate Bond
picb = pd.read_csv (r'.\CSV Files\picb.csv')
picb.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

#and so on.
```

I am trying to make the code more dry. My approach so far:

```
import pandas as pd

def readfile(ticker):
    data_folder="(r'./CSV Files/"
    file=data_folder + "{}.csv')".format(ticker)
    #return file yields: "(r'./CSV Files/urth.csv')"
    df=pd.read_csv {}.format(file)
    return df
    
readfile('urth')
```

I get the following traceback:

```
  File "<ipython-input-111-c85ffca58d7f>", line 6
    df=pd.read_csv {}.format(file)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems like i need to find a way to get rid of the "" in my file variable so the code is excecuted as in the manual steps i showed above.

Does someone have an idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shouldn't be `df=pd.read_csv(file)`?

Answer (score 0):

The function should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def readfile(ticker):
    data_folder="./CSV Files/"
    file=data_folder + "{}.csv".format(ticker)
    #return file yields: "(r'./CSV Files/urth.csv')"
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    return df
    
readfile('urth')
```

The syntax of the `pd.read_csv` is not correct, it's missing the `()`

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks a lot for your help and taking the time! Unfortunatly i still run into a traceback:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for your help thus far. I see you relocated the brackets this time. Unfortunatly, it still returns a trace back: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "r'./CSV Files/urth.csv"                              Even though i have that csv in a folder 'CSV Files' in the same directory. I know this because the manual longer version I had before works. I found a workaround to my problem importing the data straight from the web directly. So don't feel pressured to help further! P.S. Sorry im unable to upvote your answer due to limited credits...

Comment: @meinerst I think the problem was that there was an `r` in the data_folder string. Maybe try now...